# Write units like micro gram (µg) in LaTeX

Tags: siunitx, units

How can I add a *microgram* mark in LaTeX?

Because I want to add microgram in my work as a description of a specific unit.

Comment: Take look at siunitx package

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You're probably using one of the UTF-8 capable TeXs (e.g. XeLaTeX) anyway, right? So what's the problem with just typing "µg"?

Comment: @AndreKR That depends on font coverage for appearance in output, plus there is still the whole issue of units being mathematical and so not responsive to bold/italic/...

Answer (score 22):

The `siunitx` package provides two macros that address your typesetting needs: `\si` and `\SI`.

- `\si` lets you typeset scientific units in ways that satisfy basic [SI typographic formatting conventions](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/index.html), and
- `\SI` lets you typeset numbers *and* their associated scientific units.

For more information on how scientific units should be typeset according to the *Système Inernational* (SI) conventions, please see the NIST's [SI Unit rules and style conventions](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/checklist.html).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\si{\micro\gram}, \SI{1.23}{\milli\gram}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to pick up on @leandriis's follow-up comment: The `siunitx` package provides the abbreviations `\fg`, `\pg`, `\ng`, `\ug`, `\mg`, `\g` and `\kg` for -- you guessed it -- femtogram, picogram, nanogram, microgram, milligram, gram, and kilogram. See the multi-page Table 21 of package's user guide for the full details.

Comment: `siunitx` by default also loads a number of abbreviated versions of units, so instead of `\micro\gram`, one can also use `\ug`.

Comment: @leandriis - Thanks. I've edited my answer to provide an addendum, in which I mention that the `siunitx` package provides various macros, such as `\ug`, for "abbreviated units".

Comment: From version 3 of `siunitx` the recommended approach is to now use `\qty{<number>}{<unit>}`. So this answer would become `\qty{1.23}{\ug}`

Answer (score 5):

As @Juan Castaño noted in a comment, it's perhaps best to use the `siunitx` package for this sort of thing. You could of course use `$\mu$`, but I'm not sure if that's good typographic practice (likely not).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\verb+\mu+: 100 $\mu$g

\verb+siunitx+: \SI{100}{\micro\gram}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** well, looks like @Mico beat me to answering. ;)

Comment: The use of `$\mu$g` is definitely not encouraged by the powers-that-be, *unless* the letter "mu" is typeset in an upright font face (which isn't the case in your example).

Comment: Indeed, though as always it'll also depend on who you're asking. I'm always hesitant of must-follow rules, doubly so in typography, though I would agree that the upright mu looks better here.

Comment: How can I add many paragraphs without numbering? like add abstract and background out of the formal sequences of 1- introduction and 2- methods ...etc?

Comment: @Israa it'd be best if you posted an actual new question, not just a comment on an answer.

Comment: Being a professional typographer myself (I know; rare breed!), I’d indeed advise against $ \mu $g because then it’s in italics, but $ \text{\mu} $g would be OK.

Comment: @PierrePaquette except that `\text{\mu}` would give an error because `\mu` can't be used in text mode.

Comment: Oh! Then what about just `\text{µ}`? The character could be copy/pasted from an external source, or composed with certain keyboard settings (I use Canadian–French Multilingual on a MacBook Air, and it’s alt/option-m).